# Extjs and Swing callback issue with file upload

Tags: json, swing, extjs, upload, callback

I'm building an app based on this tutorial:
    http://loianegroner.com/2011/07/extjs-4-file-upload-spring-mvc-3-example/

My client code looks like this

```
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                margins: '5 5 5 5',
                region: 'north',
                height: 52,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                title: 'Filters',
                standardSubmit: false,
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'filefield',
                                itemId: 'uploader',
                                width: 500,
                                hideLabel: true,
                                name: 'file'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'tbseparator'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                handler: function(button, e) {
                                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();

                                    if(form.isValid()){
                                        form.submit({
                                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/ItsCorrectionSvc/upload.action.json',
                                            waitMsg: 'Uploading and processing your file . . .',
                                            success: function(form, action) {
                                                //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded\n Result is ' + o.result.file);
                                                alert('Success');
                                            },
                                            failure: function(form, action){
                                                alert("Callback Failed : form is " + form + "  action is " + action.value);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }


                                },
                                id: 'submitFileButton',
                                itemId: 'submitButton',
                                text: 'Submit'
                            },
```

My server side is:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload.action")
public class FileUploadController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public String create(FileUploadBean uploadItem, BindingResult result){

    ExtJSFormResult extjsFormResult = new ExtJSFormResult();

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        for(ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()){
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getCode() +  " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }

        //set extjs return - error
        extjsFormResult.setSuccess(false);

        return extjsFormResult.toString();
    } else {
        CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile = uploadItem.getFile();
        try {
            InputStream io = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
                out.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Some type of file processing...
    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.err.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getFile().getOriginalFilename());
    System.err.println("-------------------------------------------");

    //set extjs return - success
    extjsFormResult.setSuccess(true);

    return extjsFormResult.toString();
}
```

When I run this I can see the file uploaded to my server and the server correctly prints out the contents of the file so I am successfully uploading the file.  However, when I pass the extjsFormResult back to the client it always fails.  I've also tried passing back a hard coded string of "{success:true}" just to make sure the returning object is what I expected.

I've also tried added a json filter to my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and then changed the mapping in my client to :

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/ItsCorrectionSvc/upload.action.json',
```

That should insure that my response is a properly formatted json object.

In every case the client fails the callback.  I get the alert box telling me that the callback failed and that the action is undefined.   Does anyone see why my callback is failing?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: A bit more info:  In my extjs code I'm getting a failuretype of "connect" which is supposed to mean that I can't connect with the server.  However, the server does receive the uploaded file and can print it out line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ExtJSFormResult you can always return the results success with a hashmap.Something like below the @ResponseBody will take care of the return result  format(here it is json).

```
Map results = new HashMap();
results.put("succes", true);
return results;
```

Please try once.Hope it helps you.

Comment: I gave that a try.  I'm still getting the same error message.  The callback is still going to the failure method.

Comment: @user3669653 please verify now once made changes to my answer.Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry, that still didn't work.  The thing is, all these suggestions look like they should work.  So I don't think the actual problem is the data I'm sending back.  There must be something in the transfer between the client and the server.  The client is running on localhost, the server is localhost:8080.  So I'm wondering if there is some sort of security issue which is blocking the return message.

Comment: I ended up throwing the code away and writing it in GWT.  But it would still be interesting to know why it didn't work.